# How do I fix broken/disappearing controls

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I can only guess the problem lies within the following code, but I'm not 100% sure. The problem only occurs when I try to move the CtrlComputer object in the panel in the RoomDesigner form. The aim of the code is to get the CtrlComputer object to move as one when clicked. Unfortunately without the foreach loop, moves the label1 separately, but still makes an grey box around it when dragged. See [here](https://youtu.be/nAPbYrdsFDk) for a clearer picture. I'm not sure why dragging objects around would enlarge the custom control itself.

CtrlComputer

```
public CtrlComputer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(textbox_MouseMove);
        CompButton.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(textbox_MouseMove);
        this.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(textbox_MouseMove);

    void textbox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (activeControl == null || activeControl != sender)
            return;
        foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
        {
            var location = control.Location;
            location.Offset(e.Location.X - previousLocation.X, e.Location.Y - previousLocation.Y);
            control.Location = location;
        }                    
    }
```

CtrlComputer.Designer

```
        private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.CompButton = new WindowsFormsApplication1.DoubleClickButton();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Lime;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 20);
        this.label1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 39;
        this.label1.Text = "label1";
        this.label1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        // 
        // CompButton
        // 
        this.CompButton.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.CompButton.BackgroundImage = global::SchoolAdmin.Properties.Resources.memeio;
        this.CompButton.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Center;
        this.CompButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.CompButton.Name = "CompButton";
        this.CompButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(62, 57);
        this.CompButton.TabIndex = 40;
        this.CompButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        // 
        // CtrlComputer
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.AutoSize = true;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.CompButton);
        this.Name = "CtrlComputer";
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(65, 60);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }
```

CtrlComputer - http://pastebin.com/GJ3aXJFb

Comment: I'm positive I've seen this question before... I mean I recognise the title and the `CtrlComputer` name.

Comment: By the way, as a clue to what I think is happening here... Try setting the background colour of your `CtrlComputer` control to a solid colour, like bright red.

Comment: @DavidG Yes, I fixed my question and asked if I could resubmit, I waited 2 hours and no response so I posted it again. Do you want a video of the result or just a text response?

Comment: @DavidG It feels like the form is somehow resizing the control instead of moving it :/

Comment: Looks like you should be doing drag and drop operations based on that video.  The code you posted isn't helpful since we don't have the InitializeComponent information from the designer file.

Comment: @LarsTech sorry about that, I've added it above

Comment: @larstech can you help me with this then?

Comment: @davidg can you help me with this then?

Comment: What is the size of the control you are dragging around? It looks like it's just huge and is on top of the other controls, so it hides them. Try putting a border on the control to see how it looks.